# Android: Database structure of Contact

Tags: android

I can store n number of phone no for each on Android. Number of phone no is variable, so surely there is no fixed sized structure for phone nos of each contact. So can anyone please tell me how they are structuring database for phone nos of each contact?

Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow this same structure, it will be good

[image: Contact Database Structure]

In contacts table, you use _id is for record id and used as primary key, then contact_name is name of a person.

In phone_details, _id is record id and also a primary key, then contact_id is the _id value of the  contacts table, which is a foreign key, then specify contact_type such as mobile / work/ home number and contact_no is a valid phone number

Comment: can i Use jsonb type in postgress ? I mean no rows, just a json field?